Cannot invoke "org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedVariantResult.getOwner()"
When do Gradle Sync from Android Studio:
Cannot invoke "org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedVariantResult.getOwner()" because the return value of "org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedDependencyResult.getResolvedVariant()" is null
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.1'classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.4'
}


Invalidate Caches & Restart.
Building from terminal just works.


This is reported in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/345709985
